# What is the difference between font bounding box and glyph bounding box?

Tags: pdfbox

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between font bounding box and glyph bounding box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from the [PDF specification](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (PDF32000_2008):

Font bounding box:
This is the smallest rectangle enclosing the shape that would result if all of the glyphs of the font were placed with their origins coincident and then filled. (Abbreviated as "FontBBox" on page 259).

Glyph bounding box:
The glyph bounding box shall be the smallest rectangle (oriented with the axes of the glyph coordinate system) that just encloses the entire glyph shape. (page 242)